# How to Force a Collection to be a Single Drop down menu in a form

Tags: forms, symfony

I would to create a single drop dwon menu for my user roles collection like below :

```
  class UserType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('userRoles',null, array('multiple'=>false))
            ;
        }
```

But I get this error message:

```
Expected an object, but got a collection. Did you forget to pass
"multiple=true" to an entity field?
```

Any Idea how to make a Collection not multiple selectable !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field type that you are using ("entity") expects a simple object as input if you set "multiple" to false. For your purpose, you might want to use the CallbackTransformer to transform between the collection and the object:

```
$builder->add(
    $builder->create('userRoles', null, array('multiple' => false))
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            // transform the collection to its first element
            function (Collection $coll) { return $coll[0]; },
            // transform the element to a collection
            function (MyEntity $entity) { return new ArrayCollection(array($entity)); }
        ))
);
```

If you don't use latest Symfony2 master, you should use the deprecated method `prependNormTransformer()` instead of `addModelTransformer()`.